# Object variable or With block variable not set when referencing cell using .Find

Tags: excel, vba

This worked previously but has stopped working:

```
Sub LeanCut()
Dim lrow As Long

Cells.Find(What:="~*~*~* Total*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False).Activate
Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete

lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A10:I" & lrow).Select

End Sub
```

I'm getting Runtime error 91 on line

```
Cells.Find(What:="~*~*~* Total*", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False).Activate
```

The script is supposed to find the cell that contains "~~~ Total" and delete it along with everything below it, then select the range above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update sheet name (`????`)

```
Option Explicit

Sub LeanCut()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("????")
Dim lrow As Long, Found As Range

lrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Found = ws.Cells.Find(What:="~*~*~* Total*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row, 1), ws.Cells(lrow, 9)).Delete
Else
    MsgBox "Value not found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would also like to add some reasoning for the OP: `ActiveCell` references the currently selected cell on the currently visible sheet. Using the `ActiveCell` instead of a fully qualified reference means that if the wrong sheet is selected at the time the code runs, the code won't run on the expected sheet.

Comment: Hmm, getting type mismatch on `: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("love")` (my worksheet is named "love" for simplicity sake)

Comment: Yeah, it's the sheet name. I typo'd there. The sheet is "love"

Comment: Thanks, that got it! It's telling me it can't find the value for whatever reason, but I'll tweak around with it to see what I can do. The value in the cell in question is "*** Total            " so I used the * after Total to capture those spaces, but they won't snag. I'll see if I can work with it somehow though, as long as this works out.

Comment: AH! I figured out what was wrong!!! Turns out that the spaces after Total were special characters, not spaces. My report formatted the cell in a strange way, so neither script was able to find the cell because the value had those weird characters in. I changed them to account for those and it works just fine now!